# How to compute the disassembly of a Java class at _runtime_?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, disassembly, load-time-weaving

I'm trying to investigate whether [*dynamic weaving*](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm) is being applied to my classes.

First, here's some context…

---

It is very easy to prove whether *static weaving* is occurring. You use `javap -c MyCoolEntity` to see the disassembly of some Java class `MyCoolEntity.class`.

In this example: `MyCoolEntity` is a class describing a JPA entity. It is possible to use a plugin in our build process to "weave" its bytecode.

A getter which represents a *JPA entity relationship* will — in *non-weaved* bytecode — look like a simple field lookup:

```
public java.util.List<com.stackoverflow.Friend> getFriends();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #222                // Field friends:Ljava/util/List;
     4: areturn
```

But *weaved* bytecode delegates the call to a virtual method, `_persistence_get_*()`:

```
public java.util.List<com.stackoverflow.Friend> getFriends();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: invokevirtual #640                // Method _persistence_get_friends:()Ljava/util/List;
     4: areturn
```

This weaved bytecode can be used to achieve a *lazy-lookup* (fetch the related entity on-demand from the database).

---

I expect that I can apply the same logic to ascertain whether *dynamic weaving* is occurring in my application.

My understanding is this: a Java agent transforms the class bytecode *at runtime*.

**Is there a way I can access the `.class` file that my JPA implementation's Java agent produces at run-time?** Otherwise: is there a way that I can connect to the running JVM and perform a disassembly on the class that it holds in-memory?

---

Disclaimer: my question is primarily concerned with "how do you grab & disassemble a `.class` file that is generated at runtime". There are likely *other* ways to answer the sub-question "is dynamic weaving occurring?", but that part is not the primary focus of my question. :)

For what it's worth: I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1 and TomCat 8.5.

Comment: I don't think the JVM provides any mechanism to extract the raw class data for a loaded class (as opposed to reflective abstractions of the same).  In particular, it is unlikely that there is any actual file containing that data, but even in the more general sense you probably mean, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Have a look at the ASM library and see if it can take in a class object; if it does then you can use its API to introspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) and do something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;

public class MethodDisassembler {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Class<?> clazz = MethodDisassembler.class;
    String classAsPath = clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    try (InputStream classStream = clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath)) {
      ClassParser classParser = new ClassParser(classStream, classAsPath);
      JavaClass javaClass = classParser.parse();
      for (Method method : javaClass.getMethods())
        System.out.println(method.getCode());
    }
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    sendEmail();
  }

  public void sendEmail() {
    System.out.println("Sending e-mail");
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Code(max_stack = 1, max_locals = 1, code_length = 5)
0:    aload_0
1:    invokespecial java.lang.Object.<init>:()V (8)
4:    return

Attribute(s) = 
LineNumber(0, 10)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 5, index = 0:de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MethodDisassembler this)
Code(max_stack = 5, max_locals = 12, code_length = 165)
0:    ldc       de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MethodDisassembler (1)
2:    astore_1
3:    new       <java.lang.StringBuilder> (19)
6:    dup
7:    aload_1
8:    invokevirtual java.lang.Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String; (21)
11:   bipush        46
13:   bipush        47
15:   invokevirtual java.lang.String.replace:(CC)Ljava/lang/String; (27)
18:   invokestatic  java.lang.String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; (33)
21:   invokespecial java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V (37)
24:   ldc       ".class" (40)
26:   invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; (42)
29:   invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String; (46)
32:   astore_2
33:   aconst_null
34:   astore_3
35:   aconst_null
36:   astore        %4
38:   aload_1
39:   invokevirtual java.lang.Class.getClassLoader:()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; (49)
42:   aload_2
43:   invokevirtual java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream; (53)
46:   astore        %5
48:   new       <org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser> (59)
51:   dup
52:   aload     %5
54:   aload_2
55:   invokespecial org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.<init>:(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;)V (61)
58:   astore        %6
60:   aload     %6
62:   invokevirtual org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse:()Lorg/apache/bcel/classfile/JavaClass; (64)
65:   astore        %7
67:   aload     %7
69:   invokevirtual org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.getMethods:()[Lorg/apache/bcel/classfile/Method; (68)
72:   dup
73:   astore        %11
75:   arraylength
76:   istore        %10
78:   iconst_0
79:   istore        %9
81:   goto      #105
84:   aload     %11
86:   iload     %9
88:   aaload
89:   astore        %8
91:   getstatic     java.lang.System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream; (74)
94:   aload     %8
96:   invokevirtual org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method.getCode:()Lorg/apache/bcel/classfile/Code; (80)
99:   invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (86)
102:  iinc      %9  1
105:  iload     %9
107:  iload     %10
109:  if_icmplt     #84
112:  aload     %5
114:  ifnull        #164
117:  aload     %5
119:  invokevirtual java.io.InputStream.close:()V (92)
122:  goto      #164
125:  astore_3
126:  aload     %5
128:  ifnull        #136
131:  aload     %5
133:  invokevirtual java.io.InputStream.close:()V (92)
136:  aload_3
137:  athrow
138:  astore        %4
140:  aload_3
141:  ifnonnull     #150
144:  aload     %4
146:  astore_3
147:  goto      #162
150:  aload_3
151:  aload     %4
153:  if_acmpeq     #162
156:  aload_3
157:  aload     %4
159:  invokevirtual java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (97)
162:  aload_3
163:  athrow
164:  return

Exception handler(s) = 
From    To  Handler Type
48  112 125 <Any exception>(0)
38  138 138 <Any exception>(0)

Attribute(s) = 
LineNumber(0, 12), LineNumber(3, 13), LineNumber(33, 14), LineNumber(38, 14), 
LineNumber(48, 15), LineNumber(60, 16), LineNumber(67, 17), LineNumber(91, 18), 
LineNumber(102, 17), LineNumber(112, 19), LineNumber(164, 20)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 165, index = 0:java.lang.String[] args)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 3, length = 162, index = 1:java.lang.Class clazz)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 33, length = 132, index = 2:java.lang.String classAsPath)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 48, length = 88, index = 5:java.io.InputStream classStream)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 60, length = 52, index = 6:org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser classParser)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 67, length = 45, index = 7:org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass javaClass)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 91, length = 11, index = 8:org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method method)
LocalVariableTypes(start_pc = 3, length = 162, index = 1:java.lang.Class<?>... clazz)
StackMap((FULL, offset delta=84, locals={(type=Object, class=[Ljava.lang.String;), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Class), (type=Object, class=java.lang.String), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable), (type=Object, class=java.io.InputStream), (type=Object, class=org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser), (type=Object, class=org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass), (type=Bogus), (type=Integer), (type=Integer), (type=Object, class=[Lorg.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;)}), (SAME, offset delta=20), (FULL, offset delta=19, locals={(type=Object, class=[Ljava.lang.String;), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Class), (type=Object, class=java.lang.String), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable), (type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable), (type=Object, class=java.io.InputStream)}, stack items={(type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable)}), (CHOP 1, offset delta=10), (SAME_LOCALS_1_STACK, offset delta=1, stack items={(type=Object, class=java.lang.Throwable)}), (SAME, offset delta=11), (SAME, offset delta=11), (CHOP 2, offset delta=1))
Code(max_stack = 1, max_locals = 1, code_length = 5)
0:    aload_0
1:    invokevirtual de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MethodDisassembler.sendEmail:()V (124)
4:    return

Attribute(s) = 
LineNumber(0, 23), LineNumber(4, 24)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 5, index = 0:de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MethodDisassembler this)
Code(max_stack = 2, max_locals = 1, code_length = 9)
0:    getstatic     java.lang.System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream; (74)
3:    ldc       "Sending e-mail" (127)
5:    invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V (129)
8:    return

Attribute(s) = 
LineNumber(0, 27), LineNumber(8, 28)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 9, index = 0:de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MethodDisassembler this)
```

I guess you can figure out the rest by yourself.

---

**Update & disclaimer:** Sorry, I have ovelooked the requirement that this should be done for instrumented classes, i.e. classes which have changed during classloading as compared to the original class files on disk. In this case I suggest to write your own little Java agent and put it after your weaving agent (whatever it may be, AspectJ or something else) in the chain of agents, then use the instrumentation API itself or BCEL again in order to find out if the class was correctly instrumented before.

**Update 2:** [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/retrieving_class_files_from_a) you see how you can dump the binary class from an instrumentation agent as suggested above. You can still decide whether you want to store the bytes on disk or want to buffer them in a byte array in memory and read them from there via BCEL via a `ByteArrayInputStream`. But this seems pretty contrived if you need it outside of integration tests. During runtime in production maybe you do not want to use it, or at least only sparingly as a quick smoke test when booting up your application.

Comment: So, we're not really going to use it, but just to widen my knowledge: do I really have to use Java agent to enable dynamic weaving? Can't I just swap ClassLoader for my own which will transform byte code before returning it?

Comment: This is a very general question, so I can also just answer in a very general way: yes, probably. But then you need to assure that your target classes are actually loaded by that very classloader. How about describing which problem you actually want to solve instead of asking questions about a technical solution which you assume is right but really is maybe unsuited to your problem?

Comment: we've just made a move from GlassFish to TomCat. As I understand it, GlassFish supported load-time weaving out of box, while TomCat doesn't (you need to start it with a specific java agent for that). We have enabled static weaving because of it, but were also discovering other options which wouldn't require specifying java agent (which is PITA with maven). I asked about class loader more just out of curiosity (I'm new to Java). Thanks.

Comment: AspectJ weaving should work nicely with Tomcat. But we are getting off-topic. Maybe you want to open another, more specific question if you have a concrete use case and problems with it. I think I answered your original question correctly, so I would appreciate you accepptung my answer.